# Is filter_input-regexp enough for inputs with "little freedom" ?

Tags: php, security, xss

I'm currently building a website which allows some put not much user input. I always know what sort of characters is allowed and which one are not. For instance, all of the inputs are either alphanumeric, emails or have a few more allowed symbols such as .$!?&@**-+. (passwords)

At the moment, I always check before using any input, and I do this with the filter_input function of php, using filters like

```
filter_var( $post['var'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array( "options"=>array( "regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/")
filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array( "options"=>array( "regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\$\-\_\!\£\@\#\*\:\?\&]+$/") )
```

I'd like to later on only use the validate with regexp, because it seems the best choice in terms of deciding exactly what to approve and what to refuse.

The problem is I am a bit paranoid, so I'd like to know if for the usage explained initially ( <([{"'/ .. are never allowed for example ) it is safe to simply use the validation through regexp.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the execution is terminated immediately after validation of some field fails, and you use a white-list approach in the regexp, then yes, it will be sufficient. There are some things (like emails) that can be validated by native PHP functions, but in general there is no reason to avoid regular expressions.

It does not protect you from SQL injections, though. This matter has to be addressed separately.

Comment: Yes the execution is indeed terminated as the information is usually necessary to proceed anyway.

Regarding MySQL, is a simple prepared statement enough ?

Comment: You should pass each parameter individually and parameters should be typed (numbers are really converted to numbers, strings are escaped, etc.) - that's the general idea of SQL injection prevention.